# How can I refresh a tab when it becomes visible to the user?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tabs

I am using a Fragment State Pager Adapter to handle the creation of the different fragments.

In my application the beginning tabs is where a user will enter in data and the last tab shows a report based on the beginning tabs.

The problem is that when I get to the report tab, everything is shown correctly except for the previous tabs information. It seems that it is creating the tab before it becomes visible.

Is there any way to make only the report tab load when it becomes visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to update the tab, I had to notify the data set has changed to the adapter and then reset it on the view pager.

```
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            if(tab.getPosition() == areas.size()){
                roundPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                viewPager.setAdapter(null);
                viewPager.setAdapter(roundPagerAdapter);
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            } else {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can override **setUserVisibleHint** method to get notified about the visibility of the framgent

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment#setuservisiblehint

Comment: How would I call to to recreate the fragment?

Comment: You don't need to re-create the fragment, you can just reload the data

Answer (score 0):

```
    OnPageChangeListener myOnPageChangeListener = new OnPageChangeListener(){ 
@Override public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
 //Called when the scroll state changes.

 } 

@Override public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
 //This method will be invoked when the current page is scrolled, //either as part of a programmatically initiated smooth scroll //or a user initiated touch scroll. 
} 


@Override public void onPageSelected(int position) {
//This method will be invoked when a new page becomes selected. 

        textMsg.append("onPageSelected:" + position + "\n"); }};
```

Now add this listener to your viewpager

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(myOnPageChangeListener)
```